# How to flatten boxed slice of arrays?

Tags: arrays, rust, casting

Can I somehow flatten a boxed slice `Box<[[T;SIZE]]>` into `Box<[T]>`? Using `unsafe` is okay if necessary. I own the box and I want to do it in-place without making unnecessary copies.

It is more complex than it looks. It is necessary to modify `PtrComponents::metadata` (this heap variable holds length of array) as is shown in [the source for slice `len`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#137). If you don't take this into account and just transmute the box, it doesn't have the correct length.

Answer (score 1):

This can be written like so:

```
pub fn flatten_box<T, const DIM: usize>(v: Box<[[T; DIM]]>) -> Box<[T]> {
    let old_len = v.len();
    let old_ptr = Box::into_raw(v);
    
    let new_len = old_len.checked_mul(DIM).expect("slice len overflow");
    let new_ptr: *mut T = old_ptr.cast();
    
    let new = std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut(new_ptr, new_len);

    // SAFETY: the pointer was derived from an existing Box::into_raw call
    // and has the original size and alignment and there are no outstanding
    // references to the data
    unsafe { Box::from_raw(new) }
}
```

To explain: we have to deconstruct the `Box` into its raw components and reconstruct a new one with the new type and length. Using `slice_from_raw_parts_mut` is the way to construct the pointer with the correct metadata for a slice. You don't have to mess with `ptr::metadata` for this.

Comment: This function is wrong (although probably not unsound) in one subtle part: if `T` is a ZST, it is possible for `old_len * DIM` to overflow. This function silently ignores that on release builds. The correct thing is to panic, like [`<[T]>::flatten()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.flatten).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman you know, I was looking at that function for reference but kind of glossed over why ZSTs did their multiplication differently... I've updated the code

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay with using nightly, you can use [`Vec::into_flattened()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_flattened). Converting `Box<[T]>` to `Vec<T>` is always zero-cost; converting `Vec<T>` to `Box<[T]>` is zero-cost if the `Vec` has no excess capacity (which is always the case if it originated from `Box<[T]>`).

```rust
#![feature(slice_flatten)]

pub fn flatten_box<T, const N: usize>(v: Box<[[T; N]]>) -> Box<[T]> {
    Vec::from(v).into_flattened().into_boxed_slice()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```rust
fn transmute<T, const N: usize>(b: Box<[[T; N]]>) -> Box<[T]> {
    // SAFETY: raw pointer is created from Box and
    // *mut [[T; N]] has the same aligment as *mut [T]
    unsafe { Box::from_raw(Box::into_raw(b) as *mut [T]) }
}
```

EDIT. This doesn't preserve the length of a slice. See comment below by @eggyal for solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249283/discussion-on-answer-by-aleksander-krauze-flatten-boxed-slice-of-arrays).